# Speech Recognition does not trigger EventHandler in C++/CLI DLL

Tags: events, dll, c++-cli, speech-recognition, teamspeak

I have a TS3 plugin in creation right here, which uses 
`System::Speech::Recognition` for its `SpeechRecognitinEngine`. Now, I create an EventHandler for the `SpeechRecognized` event.

Well, my logging (and the actions of the plugin - None) tell me, that the Event is actually never triggered, even if you start and stop talking with the (somewhat) valid (parts of the) grammar.

I have no idea why this is. It happens in a DLL written in C++ CLI.
Now, my theory was that DLLs do not support event handerls... Might that be possible?

```
void recogn_speech() {
    uint64 schid = ts3Functions.getCurrentServerConnectionHandlerID();

    SpeechRecognitionEngine^ recognizer = gcnew SpeechRecognitionEngine();

    System::Speech::Recognition::Grammar^ g = assembleGrammar();
    recognizer->LoadGrammar(g);
    recognizer->SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

    char pluginPath[PATH_BUFSIZE];
    ts3Functions.getPluginPath(pluginPath, PATH_BUFSIZE, pluginID);
    String^ a = gcnew String(pluginPath);
    a = a + "vctest_cpp_ts3\\signal_vc_start.wav";
    char* newPath = (char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(a);
    ts3Functions.playWaveFile(schid, newPath);
    Marshal::FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)newPath);

    recognizer->SpeechRecognized += 
        gcnew EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs^>(this, &tsapi::sre_SpeechRecognized);
}

void sre_SpeechRecognized(Object^ sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs^ e)
{
    uint64 schid = ts3Functions.getCurrentServerConnectionHandlerID();
    String^ recognRes = e->Result->Text->ToString();
    interpretCommand(recognRes);
}
```

Full Sourcecode on
[GitHub](https://github.com/WhOoKie/TS3WKVC/blob/master/plugin.cpp#L211)

Comment: The most obvious reason is that it simply does not recognize anything.  Verify that speech recognition is functional in general without a grammar.  The not-obvious reason is what is missing in the GitHub code.  The host program could lie about the thread on which this code runs, declaring it an STA thread but not actually pumping a message loop.

Comment: So how do I fix that? Or different: How do I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler looks correct. There's no issue with having events & event handlers across DLLs: It's all managed code, the DLL boundary doesn't matter here.

However, there is one possible issue:

```
void recogn_speech() {
    ...
    SpeechRecognitionEngine^ recognizer = gcnew SpeechRecognitionEngine();
    ...
}
```

You might want to save your SpeechRecognitionEngine object somewhere so it doesn't get garbage collected.

Also, you may want to switch to the more C++-style of having class definitions in .h files, and implementations in .cpp files. As your code gets more complex and the classes need to refer to each other, having everything in one file will start to become an issue.

Comment: Done declaring the functions in the header file, also made recognizer not be garbage collected... Still does not trigger the SpeechRecognized event.

Comment: Then it sounds like your problem is with the speech recognition, not with the event handler.